# c++ windows service with curl

Tags: c++, windows, service, libcurl

I am new to c++ and programming close to operating system level (as my programming knowlege comes from web background), yet I need to build windows service that will communicate with remote server via HTTP.
I as far as I was able to figure out, one way is to use libcurl, but I lack knowledge on how to implement other libraries into my project, I am also concerned even if I make everything work, how it will work on clients computer, will libcurl will go along side service executable, or if it ill not work since client will not have that library installed in his computer?

I am not expecting straightforward answer, but some guidance and directions and what and where I should investigate.
Any advises on related topic is apprenticed, appropriate literature even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the link how to include the dynamic libraries http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms235636.aspx.

After inclusion of library you should have to include libcurl header which has exposed the API to connect to HTTP.

Yes libcurl will go along side service executable as a dll file.

Read how to use libcurl in c++ project from. http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/visual_studio.pdf
or 
[Using LibCURL C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876536/using-libcurl-c?rq=1)