# Having trouble trying to link libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl, dev-c++

I'm trying to install libcurl for Bloodshed Dev C++ but I'm running into a couple of issues.
I've included the curl directory under Dev-Cpp\MinGW\include and have placed the library files (which I compiled myself using MinGW) in the Dev-Cpp\MinGW\lib directory. I have added all the libraries I'm using to the Linker tab under Project> Project Options> Parameters.

Here is the code I'm using to test libcurl:

```
    #define CURL_STATICLIB
#include "curl/curl.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {
    CURLcode ret;
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed creating CURL easy handle!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*Attempt to get Facebook*/
    ret = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.facebook.com");
    if (ret != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed getting http://www.google.com: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(ret));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed getting http://www.google.com: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(ret));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, the error `enter code here`I'm getting is this:

```
skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/libcurl.a when searching for -lcurl
skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/libcurl.dll when searching for -lcurlskipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib\libcurl.a when searching for -lcurl
skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../lib/libcurl.a when searching for -lcurl
skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../lib/libcurl.dll when searching for -lcurl
skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../lib\libcurl.a when searching for -lcurl
skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../libcurl.a when searching for -lcurl
skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../libcurl.dll when searching for -lcurl
skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../..\libcurl.a when searching for -lcurl
skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/libcurl.a when searching for -lcurl
skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/libcurl.dll when searching for -lcurl
skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../lib/libcurl.a when searching for -lcurl
skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../lib/libcurl.dll when searching for -lcurl
skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../libcurl.a when searching for -lcurl
skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../libcurl.a when searching for -lcurl
cannot find -lcurl
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status  
recipe for target 'Test.exe' failed
```

I am thoroughly stuck, and would deeply appreciate someone calling me an idiot and telling me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Most likely, trying to mix 32 and 64 bit objects.

Comment: I see, will using the win64 version libcurl help?

Comment: It is not related to your question, but change to another IDE/Compiler, Dev C++ is outdated. If you want to stick with mingw or cygwin you can use better IDE's and compile using the mingw/cygwin gcc, clang.

Answer (score 1):

"skipping incompatible" usually indicates a architecture mismatch. A wild guess is that you should add -m32 in your compile flags. (or -m64, but judging from the installation path -m32 looks more likely.)

(Unrelated to the question, but I can't help but notice that your code is requesting facebook.com and printing a error mentioning google.com.)

Comment: Neither m32 nor m64 helped, and I didn't pay much attention to the code, since its just meant to be a test. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: "Neither m32 nor m64 helped" Did you get exactly the same error messages with -m32 and -m64?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by switching to Codeblocks, using a different distribution and following the tutorial listed below.

[Using LibCURL C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876536/using-libcurl-c)