# -libcurl linker "cannot find"

Tags: c++, curl, linker, libcurl

I'm following this quasi-tutorial here on making curl work:
[Using LibCURL C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876536/using-libcurl-c)

I'm at the point now where I've downloaded and linked the necessary file paths to my compiler and linker. However, when I run the program I get this error:

"cannot find -lcurldll"

This appears to be a linker command malfunction. In the tutorial, its instructed to put "curldll" in the link library.  I've been working on this for hours without success. What should I do? (Using Windows 10, Code :: Blocks)

Comment: Is this windows os?

Comment: Yes, this is Windows 10, using Codeblocks, mingw gcc compiler.

Comment: Never used windows to compile c++.  On Linux you would need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to put the command without the -l in the linker.